What preliminary research is Beit Din required to do before initiating a divorce case?
In a previous question, I asked "Is a Defendant required to appear in Beth Din if the Plaintiff doesn't provide any evidence or witnesses?".
The question was very helpfully answered by @terryg, citing Choshen Misphat 75.1 which provides the rules Beit Din must follow to ascertain the basic validity of financial claims being made before commencing a case.
In this question I am asking if anyone can help me determine if there are similar rules in the area of family law, that is, where one spouse summons the other to Beit Din.
Suppose Chava, a woman married to a man named Adam, is prone to outbursts of anger and frustration in her marriage. In one episode, after a disagreement over Chanukkah plans, she sends a summons from Beit Din to Adam, demanding that he divorce her. Adam tells the Beit Din that his wife is just acting up and she doesn't mean it, and that he is a good husband to her.
Is the Beit Din required to do any preliminary examination into Chava's claims for divorce (similar to the rules in cases of financial lawsuits), or must Adam appear for a trial simply by virtue of a summons having been sent?

If the beit din did make a summons, he has to go. Your question should start earlier: how does the beit din determine whether to issue the summons?

@ClintEastwood Yes that is precisely my question. What does a Beit Din have to do to determine whether to issue the summons?
